# How to convert json to javascript object that using existing method?

Tags: javascript, json

I have an object like this:

```
function Point(x,y)
{
    this.coorX = x;
    this.coorY = y;
}

function Node(id,x,y)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.point = new Point(x,y);

    this.getDescription = function(){
         return this.id + ': (' + this.punto.coorX + ', ' +  this.punto.coorY + ')';
    }

}
```

I export a list of node in json format with:

```
 JSON.stringify(NodeList);
```

json:

```
 {"NodeList":[{"id":0,"point":{"coorX":15,"coorY":15},"$$hashKey":"004"},{"id":1,"point":{"coorX":15,"coorY":151},"$$hashKey":"009"},{"id":2,"point":{"coorX":25,"coorY":15},"$$hashKey":"00E"}]}
```

After if I import the same json with:

```
 NodeList = JSON.parse(text);
```

After the import how can I use the `Node` function `getDescription()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recreate your nodes, like so:

```
var items = NodeList.NodeList,
    nodes = [];

for(var i = 0; i < items.lenght; i++) {
    var item = items[i],
        point = item.point,
        node = new Node(item.id, point.coorX, point.coorY);

    nodes.push(node);
}

// call getDescription of first node
nodes[0].getDescription();
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON is not a programming language. It supports *data* as opposed to *methods*.

Comment: [JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a lightweight data-interchange format.](http://www.json.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I've created a GitHub-Gist that does exactly this:
https://gist.github.com/Hoff97/7518680

Use jsonWF,objWF for de and encoding.

I've got another Gist that does the same thing more efficiently and is also able to convert cyclic objects: https://gist.github.com/Hoff97/9842228

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged. Please explain your approach. It seems interesting enough.

Comment: Ok, so the jsonWF function actually replaces all methods by properties that contain the actual method code. When converting the JSON-string back to an object, all properties containing method code are converted back to methods.

Comment: Um, there seems to be recursion and meta-programing involved (I'm not a fan of either). I'm sure you would get quite a few rep points if you took the time to explain the recursive process of inflating the methods/functions with assignFuncFromStr. I'd gladly vote your answer up if you explained some of the drawbacks with this approach as well as give some examples of where such a solution is reasonable to use.

Comment: Actually i would recommend using my second approach, because its cleaner and does the same thing way faster.